# Drive auto mounting as read only (errors=remount-ro)

Tags: mount

My system is auto-mounting as read only and I have no idea why.

Output of fstab:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=28db2489-f60e-456c-9efd-7a961f3e970a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=106e4470-d734-4cec-98a6-c7859aaedf18 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Output of mount:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

I have searched all night including:
[Ubuntu 12.04 SSD root frequent random read only file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262717/ubuntu-12-04-ssd-root-frequent-random-read-only-file-system)

I have no idea why this is going on. I did run fsck at boot and it didn't find errors.

The disk is fine (500GB, user 38GB)

Answer (score 0):

When you say you ran the `fsck` at boot and didn't find any errors, do you know that from watching it run or from the log files in `/var/log/fsck`? If it's from those log files, know that they haven't worked in years ([see bug 513644](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/513644)).

How do you know your drive has no errors? Did you run the manufacturer tool from a boot CD such as [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)?

I would boot to a LiveUSB/LiveCD and check the filesystem manually:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

Comment: A path in Linux has no backslashes.

Comment: @A.B. The other path already has forward slashes.

Comment: Yes, I know. What do you mean?