# Why is my system intermittently becoming read only at ~8:00 am every sunday?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, hard-drive, ssd, migration

Ever since following [this](https://frankfzw.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/migrate-ubuntu-14-04-from-hdd-to-ssd/) tutorial to migrate my sistem from my HDD to my SSD I have been getting an intermittent error where running any command I get something like this:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/foo/0: Read-only file system
sudo: unable to execute /sbin/fsck: Input/output error
```

And the only way I can fix it is by hard rebooting my machine.

This used to happen ruffly once every two weeks and I have no idea why.

Now it happens every Sunday at ~8:00 am.

I really have no idea where to start when debugging this issue any tips would be greatly appreciated. I have done tests on my RAM and on my SDD but nothing seems to be untoward to me. I am sorry for such an open ended question but I am desperate to solve this issue ASAP.

## EDIT:

Replaced the 2010 sandisk SSD and hasn't happened since. Moral of the story - don't buy old SSDs on eBay :)

Comment: any info in /var/log/ that might help?

Comment: Nothing obvious no.

Comment: If it's on a regular time interval, I'd start poking around cron, perhaps there's some script with a typo in there. When it goes RO, does `mount` show that it's read only? If so, it was (re)mounted that way (autofs perhaps), if not, then it might be the ssd drivers. Have you tried updating your system?

Comment: Same here, but with FAT32?

Comment: @Maximilian look into your `/etc/crontab` file. The fact that it occurs on specific day of week and specific time, suggests you might have a scheduled cronjob.  Look for entries  with 8 in second column.

Comment: @Serg yesterday it was at 07:52

Comment: I would ask for the content of `/var/log/syslog` around the last time this issue occurred, but `/var` is on the file system that was just switched to read-only. However you can poke around in the output of `dmesg -T` which resides in a memory buffer but it doesn't reach too far back.

Comment: This is the dmesg: http://pastebin.com/1zEN8Ju3

Comment: Why not just reinstall Ubuntu? It's possible to reinstall without losing your data. See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/841310/518562

Comment: @AndroidDev I am 200 miles away from my server

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force a check of all file systems skipping mounted ones with the -M option

```
 sudo fsck -Af -M
```

If it fails perhaps you can try for ext4 filesystems

```
 sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1 > fsck-output.txt
```

You can change to ext3 depending on your filesystem type.

The Recommended filesystem for Linux systems would be **EXT4 with TRIM** intended to improve performance through reduced write cycles to the SSD drive given the limited write-rewrite cycles.

Check for output in the **fsck-output.txt** file for any errors or use dmesg to get any errors not printed on screen and let me know how it goes.

Regards Douglas and hope it works out.

Comment: Thank you! It returns `fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve ...` which is the main ssd drive!?

Comment: what file system are you running?

Comment: running `ext4` just ran `blkid` and the ssd uuid is completely different. How come it still works haha?

Comment: they have to be the same

Comment: I know but how are they still working if they are not?

Comment: you can change it **sudo tune2fs /dev/sdeX -U UUID_HERE** replace X with the partition number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40888/discussion-between-olu-douglas-and-maximilian).

Comment: It happened again :(

Comment: Hi @Maximilian... what happpened again?

Comment: The system became read only!

Comment: @Maximilian I think your drive's life span is downing. but try this link first [http://askubuntu.com/questions/262717/ubuntu-12-04-ssd-root-frequent-random-read-only-file-system]

Comment: this is my [dmesg](http://pastebin.com/1zEN8Ju3) output during the issue! I will look at the link now!

Comment: It also happens every week at 7am on Sunday

Comment: every week... sounds like a cron job is triggering it

Comment: it is not. I have checked them all. :(

Comment: around 7am. 3am - 9am

Answer (score 0):

Since this error started with the new SSD, I'd recommend checking the connection. If the disk is connected via SATA, that means both ends of the cable: Unplug and plug in again.

If the problem does not disappear, I'd recommend checking the SSD itself with whatever you have available. There might be some low-level tools from the manufacturer, there might be some data in the SMART logs.