# Trouble recovering after release upgrade

Tags: unity, wireless, upgrade, upstart

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 16.04 when the process failed. After the computer rebooted itself, I found a problem with the bootloader, which would throw me back to BIOS setup. I fixed that with the Ubuntu install disk.

Now I have access to tty1-tty6. I found out that Unity dash was missing. I managed to run "startx", so now I am able to open gfx applications from the terminal, but all the panels and elements of unity dash, as well as borders of windows are missing.

Also, I can't install the needed packages, because I can't connect to Wi-Fi. I don't have an Ethernet hub in my laptop so Wi-Fi is the only option. It seems to me that the driver is missing. I downloaded bcmwl-kernel-source, but dpkg won't install it. It throws some C compilation error. I tried several builds with no success.

At this point I am really frustrated because I just can't Google an answer anymore and I have no idea what to do. I need to recover access to Wi-Fi but I have no idea how.

Comment: And this is why, *IMHO*, OS upgrades (regardless of whether it's Windows, OSX, or Linux) should always be avoided. I suggest you perform a clean install.

Comment: @AndroidDev I think they should be avoided in most cases for different reasons. You can easily protect yourself from this trouble by creating a copy of the disk's image prior to upgrading the OS which is super easy with a GNU Linux system which provides live sessions. @ OP: Do you have a big external medium to store all of your personal files?

Comment: @AndroidDev Your mileage may vary greatly. Upgrades are convenient, and work reasonably well (done many with zero problems), but sometimes they don't. It's always advised to have a plan b, aka recovery strategy. PS: ...looks like there is no recovery for the OP, time to reinstall.

Comment: @mikewhatever Okay, but there must definitely be a way to recover from this situation... Can one install Ubuntu on top of an old installation? Probably there's a way to backup all the software and data and do a clean install to than re-use it?

Comment: @АрсенГоян - You can follow my answer for reinstalling without losing data here: http://askubuntu.com/a/841310/518562