# Login loop with Nvidia drivers (another one)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

*Now before you read anything else - YES I know there are endless questions about this. But none have worked. NONE.*

So I've been facing a very frustrating problem twice now. I first have everything smooth (example: Minecraft with 60 FPS, even though some annoying flickering). Then I do something stupid.

First time I accidentally installed an Intel driver even though I had Nvidia.
This time - I was stuck in a fullscreen application, couldn't use Ctrl+Alt+F1 because of an error I later fixed, but so I decided to do the Magic Keys combination... Except I typed ROFUS instead of REISUB for some reason. Now it should've shutten down at O and ignored the rest, but still

But after this, randomly my drivers are uninstalled. Everything is super slow, (example: Minecraft is 10 FPS).

So what I do is I mess with the driver. WHATEVER I do with it, whether it's changing to a propietary driver or doing it manually in the command prompt or whatever... It causes a login loop.

**Here is what I have tried:**
(Of course I ran some commands on sudo)
Last time:
Moved/Deleted et.c et.c on some .Xa file everybody was talking about.
More stuff like that people with a *different* issue had.

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

apt install nvidia-current
```

Now:
Adding the graphic drivers PPA

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The ONLY thing that worked (both times):

```
apt purge nvidia*
```

Yes that's right, it is IMPOSSIBLE to login if I have any nvidia- things installed. Now you might be asking "But you keep mentioning last time - How did you solve it then?".
I didn't. I had to re-install Ubuntu. It was a nightmare I never want to do again.

---

**EDIT:** It's been a really, really, long time since I posted this. But in an unrelated other question, I got my answer. The reason is NVIDIA Optimus. I can't find an Ubuntu wiki on it, but [Arch has one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus).

Comment: `nvidia-current` is very outdated. You tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: `Unable to locate package nvidia-364`
I did all commands exactly as they were given to me.

Comment: Read the note at the top of the answer. Try `nvidia-375`.

Comment: Ah! I feel stupid! It's installing now, so see you in a reboot... Hopefully

Comment: It didn't work. Still causes a login loop. I haven't uninstalled the drivers yet though, so this is written from my phone.

Comment: I suggest performing a reinstall. It is possible to reinstall and still retain your data. See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/841310/518562

Comment: So I should reinstall every time I get this error?

Comment: Sorry :3 I might have a clue what happened though... Updating in a sec

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (I'm assuming you can get a terminal on the broken PC):

Go to the NVIDIA website and download the latest driver for your card. The Linux driver should be a ".run" file.

Put the driver on a USB stick and pop it in the broken PC.

Use this command to force it to boot into text mode:

```
sudo systemctl set-default mutli-user.target
```

And this one to reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -r 0
```

Next time the terminal comes up, log in, copy the Nvidia driver to the PC using:

```
cp <source> <destination>
```

Make sure the Nvidia file is executable by doing:

```
sudo chmod +x <driver name>
```

Run the installer by adding "./" to the start of it:

```
./<driver name>
```

When it's finished you want to tell the PC to boot back into graphical mode by doing:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

And reboot to the desktop:

```
sudo shutdown -r 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I could actually remove all Nvidia drivers (as I said) log in and download it. Running the script right now, but I see "The distribution-provided pre-install script failed! Are you sure you want to continue?". And then I have 2 buttons as in run either way or abort. What do I press?

Comment: The NVIDIA installer has worked for me before by  just letting it copy all files and config files over the top, so just go through the prompts and overwrite stuff, but have a bit of caution.

Comment: So I went through all prompts, but it still didn't work unfortunately. It's still throwing me out

Comment: Maybe you should use the command prompt to make a copy of anything important. I'm out of ideas. If no-one else can help you then you might have to do a reintstall.