# Ubuntu won't boot after removing windows and extending partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I had a dual boot (windows 10 and Ubuntu 16) on a dell laptop. I removed the windows partition and extended the Ubuntu one. Since I cannot boot Ubuntu.

I tried reinstalling GRUB with boot-repair. I cannot install it in UEFI mode:
I created a fat32 partition with boot and esp flag.
When I run oot-repair I get:

> GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted
>   filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as
>   Gparted. Then try again.

I succeeded installing GRUB in BIOS mode. When I reboot the laptop GRUB starts but Ubuntu won't.

See below the boot info summary from boot-repair with the fat32 parition:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23823238/

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What I would do is just perform a clean install of Ubuntu **in BIOS mode**, choosing the *"erase disk and install Ubuntu"* option in the installer. It is possible to reinstall without losing your data; see my answer on that here: http://askubuntu.com/a/841310/518562

Comment: Do what Boot-Repair wants you to do: 'Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.'

Comment: @sudodus, I did something like boot-repair asked, but I couldn't put a flag without formatting the partition.  And a BIOS-Boot partition is for legacy boot mode. I'd like to do it in UEFI. if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

After hours, I finally figured out how to create a boot partition in EFI.

1. Create a fat32 partition of more or less 200 MB
2. Flag it with boot and esp
3. Then copy the folder "/EFI/Boot/" from liveUSB to this boot partition.
   The partition needs two files (grubx64.efi and bootx64.efi).
4. Reboot the system without USB. From what I understood, during the boot, the system will add variables that are needed by grub-install (used by boot-repair).
5. Reboot with USB
6. Then run boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

And it should work ;-)