# How to re-insall libc6 after remove?

Tags: grub2, software-installation, glibc

I removed `libc6` manually (i.e. by `sudo apt remove libc6` command) on my Ubuntu 18.04 system and after reboot, there is just grub command prompt:

```
GNU GRUB   version 2.02

Minimal BASH_like line editing is supported. For the first word TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.


grub>  _
```

Is there any way to reinstall `libc6` and put my system working as before?

**UPDATE1:**

This is screenshot of my partition structure (as GParted shows):
[image]

`/dev/sda2` is the partition that is encrypted and contains `/etc/`, `/root/`, `/lib/`, `/run/` and other Linux OS default folders and was mounted (at my previous working Lubuntu) as `/` i.e. *system root*.

`/dev/sda5` is the partition that is not encrypted and was mounted (at my previous working Lubuntu) as `/home/` folder.

**UPDATE2:**

Although `/dev/sda5/` is not an encrypted  partition, but my `/home/myusername/` folder is encrypted as follows and I do not remember how I did this encryption during OS installation and do not know how to recover my data in my `/home/myusername/` folder:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo ls /media/lubuntu/UUID/myusername/ -la
total 12
dr-x------ 3 1000 1000 4096 Aug  1  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 25  2014 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   27 Aug  1  2013 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/myusername/.Private
drwx------ 3 1000 1000 4096 Aug  2  2013 .cache
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   28 Aug  1  2013 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/myusername/.ecryptfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   56 Aug  1  2013 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   52 Aug  1  2013 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Comment: How did you remove libc6? Using APT? Or directly deleted the binaries?

Comment: I guess you could always boot to a LiveCD following https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/231142 and after it is in chroot reinstall the libc6.

Comment: @Kulfy I removed libc6 by `apt` command and added this information in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work.

Download the `.iso` of your operating system and make a bootable USB using something like rufus. Boot from USB and when the GRUB menu appears select *Try Ubuntu without installing*.

After it boots up, the LiveUSB environment open a terminal. If you enabled LUKS in your hard drive, open the file manager enter the password. Now in the terminal run :

```
sudo pvscan    
sudo lvscan    
sudo vgchange -a y
```

This will activate the LUKS volume for mounting. Read the volume name from the output.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX/root  /mnt
```

where `sdaX` is the volume name.

If you have a separate `/boot` drive: go to the `/mnt` of LiveUSB where the filesystem is mounted. Open `/etc/fstab` and check for a `/boot` [UUID] entry and remember the drive name. Do :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/boot    
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys    
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev    
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
```

where `sdaX` is the above drive name.

Now `sudo nano /etc/hosts`. You should have two or more entries like :

```
127.0.0 localhost    
127.0.0 username
```

Copy the host address to the next line and add the host name the one you find in your terminal prompt. Should be something like *ubuntu*. Save and exit. Now :

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Reinstall `libc6` using `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade    
sudo apt install -f    
sudo update-grub    
exit
```

Unmount everything using `sudo umount /mnt/...` and reboot from OS.

PS. If `apt` does not work,maybe it depends on `libc6`, I would recommend making a backup of important files once the partition is mounted or do a reinstall without removing or repair the os.

Comment: I tried your solution. My `/home/` folder is encrypted and is a separated partition. When I click that partition in Live OS file manager, It asks me for password and after entering password, it gives following error message: `Error unlocking /dev/sda2: The function 'bd_crypto_luks_open_blob' called, but not implemented!`

Comment: Also, these three commands does not show any result:
`sudo pvscan`
`sudo lvscan`
`sudo vgchange -a y`

Comment: Run this in the live environment before trying to give the password,skip no step: sudo apt-get install libblockdev-crypto2 and systemctl restart udisks2.service.You may need to restart other services,post any error messages after this.After entering the password and opening the volume run the commands sudo pvscan etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did exactly what you told in your comment, the partition was opened after 2 mins waiting and its files are readable. But `sudo pvscan` returns: `   No matching physical volumes found` and `sudo lvscan` and `sudo vgchange -a y` return nothing! Any solution?

Comment: After opening my encrypted partition (`/dev/sda2/`) by Live OS file manager, I found my `/root/` folder in it and tried to mount whole partition on `/mnt` folder by `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` command, but it returns:  `mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.` and If I try to mount `/root` folder by `sudo mount /media/lubuntu/UUID/root /mnt` it returns: `mount: /mnt: /media/lubuntu/UUID/root is not a block device` (UUID is uu-id of my encrypted partition (`/dev/sda2` and `/media/lubuntu/UUID/` is the location it is mounted by Live OS file manager).

Comment: Maybey you don't have the package ````lvm2````,install it with ````apt````.````pvscan,lvscan,vgchange -ay```` should return a drive name like ````ubuntu-vg````. You should mount it like ````sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root/ /mnt```` since it is a LUKS volume. And before running ````lvscan```` check in the file manger if the partition is decrypted, they return blank responses if the drive is not activated with the passphrase.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the process https://ibb.co/NjZ98Fm and I ran a simulation of apt remove to check if libc6 can be reinstalled: https://pastebin.com/hFaazHi2 I don't think it can. You can try but if it fails you need to reinstall the os.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try. But it fails, how I can reinstall the OS and keep my encrypted volumes as before! I am afraid of loosing data if I reinstall the OS!

Comment: I tried to install `lvm2` but it says that `lvm2 is already the newest version`. `/dev/mapper/` contains `luks-UUID` block after decrypting the partition by file manager, but there is no `/dev/lubuntu-vg/xxx` and `pvscan, lvscan, vgchange -ay` return as before!!!

Comment: Can you please post your partition structure? Did you use LMV+LUKS while installing Ubuntu or did you encrypt only the /home folder and not the entire disk ?Where was your filesystem root? About reinstalling backup your entire /home and if you modified system files back them up.Follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/841308/installing-ubuntu-16-04-without-losing-data/841310 and/or this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation Yo'll likely loose any packages installed, so you'll need to reinstall them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101677/discussion-between-tanmap-and-php-learner).

Comment: Is there any one that could help me to solve the problem?

Comment: In order to succeed I beiieve you need to run "cryptsetup open /dev/sdXn sdXn_crypt and provide your LUKS password.

Comment: the cryptsetup command need to be run before pvscan, lvscan and vgchange.

Answer (score 0):

From Issues you faced,  it looks like more packages are missing than `libc6` and they were removed accidentally. I would suggest to mount / partition and go through apt and dpkg logs to check removed packages.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep remove
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep remove
```

Get list of packages those were removed and try to re-install them.

Comment: May be you are right, but for installing any packages if I use "-o RootDir=/mnt" option it returns `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` error and i do not know how to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` on `/mnt` as root!

Comment: i solved `chroot` problem by runing `sudo cp -a /bin/bash /mnt/bin`  ;
`sudo chmod +x /mnt/bin/bash`  ;
`sudo cp -an /usr /mnt`  ;
`sudo cp -an /lib /mnt`  ;
`sudo cp -an /lib64 /mnt`  ; and after above commands, `sudo chroot /mnt` worked!

Answer (score 0):

For mounting your encrypted partition it looks like you need `mount /media/lubuntu/UUID /mnt`. If running `apt`/`apt-get` inside the `chroot` doesn't work run it in the live CD terminal without `chroot` but with the added option `-o RootDir=/mnt`. That will put everything on the encrypted partition properly.

Comment: After running following commands:
`udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda2`  ;
`sudo mount /dev/dm-0  /mnt`  ;
`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/`  ;
`sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys/`  ;
`sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev/`  ;
`sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc/`  ;
I did following command as you sugested:
`sudo apt autoremove -o RootDir=/mnt`  ; but it returns:
`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` and running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` does not returns anythings and does not solve above error message, any suggestion?

Comment: It seems that I have to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` on my `/mnt` as root directory, but `dkpg` command does not accept `-o RootDir=/mnt` option. Is there any suggestion for how to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` on `/mnt` as root?

Comment: i solved `chroot` problem by runing `sudo cp -a /bin/bash /mnt/bin`  ;
`sudo chmod +x /mnt/bin/bash`  ;
`sudo cp -an /usr /mnt`  ;
`sudo cp -an /lib /mnt`  ;
`sudo cp -an /lib64 /mnt`  ; and after above commands, `sudo chroot /mnt` worked!