# Recover brocken libs with live USB and chroot

Tags: boot, 22.04, live-usb, chroot

I have the following problem:

I had to mingle with some libs to build a project successfully.
After I rebuild one of those libs (libtirpc) something broke and I was not able to either sudo nor use apt or other tools to somehow restore the old libtirpc version.

Now I am not even able to reboot anymore.

Can I use a live USB with the same Ubuntu ISO (Ubuntu 22.04.3) start a live session mount the root partition of my broken installation and then `chroot` into that?

Can I then use the live sessions sudo rights and e.g. apt, to reinstall libtirpc to the broken installation?

I have never used `chroot` and would be grateful for some insights before I cause even more damage!

Comment: "*Can I use a live USB ... Can I then use the live sessions sudo ...*"? ... Yes, and Yes, but your results may vary ... See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393 ... And you will have `root` powers so no need for `sudo` in the `chroot`

Comment: Thank you very much, then I will try that and hope for the best.

Comment: You don't really even need a chroot - you could use apt's `RootDir` option from the live session directly. See [How to re-insall libc6 after remove?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191350/how-to-re-insall-libc6-after-remove)